# "The hosted service is not valid" when I try to list hosted serviced in my Windows Azure subscription

Tags: windows, api, exception, azure

I'm trying to query the list of hosted services in my Windows Azure subscription. In my C# program I send a request to URL

```
https://management.core.windows.net:443/<my-subscription-id>/services/hostedservices
```

where `<my-subscription-id>` is taken from the Azure Management portal and represents a GUID as a string like this:

```
abcdef01-2345-4678-90ab-cdef0abcdef0
```

without braces or anything. I've already dealt with all sorts of certificate problems, so I assume that certificates are okay.

The response contains this XML:

```
<Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure"
   xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Code>BadRequest</Code>
      <Message>The hosted service is not valid.</Message>
</Error>
```

Which looks like of I wanted to query the status of a specific service but specified its id incorrectly. Yet [MSDN confirms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee460781.aspx) that I use the right URL for getting the list of services.

What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve this?

Comment: What happens when you remove the port information (i.e. :443)?  What is the x-ms-version header you are sending?

Comment: @dunnry: The port number is not to blame, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the following. I copy-pasted a ton of code that wrapped the REST call into an interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = ..., ConfigurationName = ...)]
public interface IAzureManagement
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = @"{subscriptionId}/services/hostedservices")]
    Services GetServices(string subscriptionId);
}
```

and used `[WebInvoke]` instead of `[WebGet]`. No idea why it makes any difference but once I changed to `[WebGet]` the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @dunnry that you should remove the 443 and in addition I would suggest that you double check that you're sending the correct subscription id.

If you're dynamically creating the request url then I'd set a breakpoint at runtime and check that the string is correct.